# switch condition not working in Android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

so i have this code:

```
package com.sunil.phpconnect;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button nao;
        Button foto;
        Button novamen;
        TextView ola;    
        HttpClient httpclient1, httpclient;
        HttpGet request1, request;
        HttpResponse response1, response;
        String url,iduser, urlmensagens;


             @Override
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              Bundle  extras = getIntent().getExtras();
              iduser= extras.getString("userid");


               TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
               //String g = result.getText().toString();
              // String h = "valor";

               urlmensagens = ("http://mywebsite.php?iduser="+iduser);
               novamen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mensagens);


                   //cenas da net
                    try {
                     httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     request1 = new HttpGet(urlmensagens);
                     response1 = httpclient1.execute(request1);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }
                    try{ 
                      BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response1.getEntity().getContent()));


                      String mensage = "";


                      mensage = dr.readLine();

                      String check_sms = mensage;

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), check_sms,
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                //novamen.setText(check_sms + " Mensagens por ler!");





                      switch(check_sms) {
                      case "b":
                          novamen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          break;
                      case "a":
                          novamen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          break;
                      default:
                          novamen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                          // Code to handle exception  

                         }

              url = ("http://mywebsite.php?action=requestuserdata&userid="+iduser);


              try {
               httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               request = new HttpGet(url);
               response = httpclient.execute(request);
              }

              catch (Exception e) {
               }


              try {
               BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 response.getEntity().getContent()));
               String line = "";
               line = rd.readLine();



                   if(line == null){
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numero nao atribuido.",
                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       Intent wowmuch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), pin.class);
                     startActivity(wowmuch);    
                   }else{
                       result.append(line);

                   }

              } catch (Exception e) {

              }

              novamen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mensagens);
                novamen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            chamaMensagens();
                            }

                        public void chamaMensagens () {

                            Intent mens = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mensagens.class);
                            mens.putExtra("userid", iduser);
                            startActivity(mens);}});


              foto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
              foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Chamafoto();
                }
                public void Chamafoto() {

                    Intent wowmuch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Foto.class);
                    wowmuch.putExtra("userid", iduser);        
                    startActivity(wowmuch);
                }
            });
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), iduser, 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              nao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                nao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            chamaConsulta();
                            }
                    }
                );
                }

                        public void chamaConsulta () {

                            Intent wowmuch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),pin.class);

                            startActivity(wowmuch); 
                        }


}
```

when i get to this part:

```
switch(check_sms) {
                          case "b":
                              novamen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              break;
                          case "a":
                              novamen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                              break;
                          default:
                              novamen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      }
```

The button is supost to be invisible/gone when whe variable "check_sms" value is "b".

I tested if the variable is showing and it is in the Toast.

I tried with if statement too and doesn't do nothing.

Comment: switch on `String`?? go for `Enum`... and I guess you have compiled src code with jdk1.7.. compile it using jdk1.6..

Comment: @DerGolem that was my thought too but if you look at the bottom they say that an if statement did not work either. I wonder could it be a case issue, are you getting B and checking it against b, i.e. try an if using .equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: You can use characters for switch case. Get character for your string and add cases like case 'a' case 'b'.

Comment: @feldoh: Because they probably tried `if (check_sms == "a")`, instead of using the **equals()** method

Comment: thats a good point too +1

Comment: @feldoh: that's another possibility. Good point, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch(someInteger)` will work.
`switch(someChar)` will work.
`switch(someEnum)` will work.
`switch(someString)` will work only in **JAVA 1.7**.

As far as I know, Java 1.7 isn't yet supported by Android.

Comment: i want to use Int insted String, but my code to connect to url and get data is getting on String variable: BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response1.getEntity().getContent()));


                      String mensage = "";


                      mensage = dr.readLine();

Comment: You can convert a character to an ASCII code. So, 'a' would be 97, 'b' would be 98, ... So, once you have your **char**: `int code = (int) character;`. Then use `switch(code)` - OR simply use `switch(character)` to save the integer conversion.

Comment: So i can do the convertion from String to Int like this : int code = (int) mensage;  ?

Comment: Obviously, NOT. mensage is a String. You could take a character out of it (say the first) and use it. Such as: `char character = mensage.toLowerCase().charAt(0);` But my best choice would be an int or an Enum. Since mensage could contain a key word that could make the difference between switching a case rather than another.

Comment: i put character = mensage.toLowerCase().charAt(1); and it works. In position  0 is giving me blank value

Comment: Probably, your string starts with a null character (ASCII 0).

Answer (score 0):

switch on `String`?? go for `Enum`... and I guess you have compiled src code with jdk1.7.. compile it using jdk1.6... jdk1.7 isn't yet supported..

Answer (score 0):

You can use string in java 1.7 only as Der Golem specified. You can use enum, char, int types. You can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html for more info.

From the above link

Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use a swich with Java 7, but in this case (only 2 options), I will use

```
if ( "a".equalsIgnoreCase( check_sms ) ){
   ....
} else {
   ....
}
```

Never use check_sms == "a" for this purpose.

Comment: your solution is not working. i previously switch have this code: if(check_sms.equals("a")){...}else{...}  but someting apens when i try to switch aplication properties encode to ISO-8859-1

Comment: Check the check_sms value with a trace, please.

Comment: how do i do a trace ?

Comment: Just before the if (your swich) write System.out.println( check_sms ); 
This will help us to see the value

Comment: System.out.println( check_sms ); didn't do nothing, but i put it in a Toast and it shows. I have my problem solved. Tnks all

Comment: Problem: i was not able to do if statement or switch with String variable, so i make this: char character = mensage.toLowerCase().charAt(1); to get the first character in the String value but now in char variable. So with the char variable i was able to do the switch.